# How to overwrite changes and avoid merge in GIT

Tags: git, github, merge

I am using GIT. We have a `master` branch. From this branch we created another branch called `test`. My friend is making changes in `test` branch while I am working on `master` branch.

I pushed my changes to `master` branch & he also pushed his changes to `test` branch to repo.

Now if I say

```
git checkout -b test
```

`git pull origin test` I get merge window.

I just want to pull content of test branch and want to overwrite my local change.

How can I avoid merging?

So far I have used this, but I am not sure if this is the right approach

```
git fetch origin test
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: You could just delete the branch and run `git checkout -t origin/test`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite your local changes which have not been committed, you can:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
git pull origin test
```

If your changes have been committed, you can:

```
git checkout <commit number>
git pull origin test
```

where commit number is the commit that origin:test branched from.

Answer (score 1):

You did two things wrong.

First to create the new branch you should do

```
git checkout -t origin/test
```

This would avoid any need to pull in the first place.

Also when you run

```
git checkout -b test
```

while in master it creates a branch named `test` with `master` as base that has no relation to `origin/test`. When you pull `origin/test` onto that branch it will try to merge them.

Comment: so you are saying if instead of using `git checkout -b test`, if I say `git checkout -t test`, it will base from test branch from origin ??

Comment: Made a booboo. It is `git checkout -t origin/test`

Comment: And yes, it will create a branch that uses `origin/test` as base and will use the branch's name in origin by default

Comment: running `git checkout -t origin/test` resulted in `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'test' at the same time.   Did you intend to checkout 'origin/test' which can not be resolved as commit`.

Comment: What is the output of your `git status`?